# New object is created everytime the server refreshes thus unable to edit the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejs-server

I have a class blockchain defined in js and I am creating its object within the same file.
The moment I run the server the object gets created and I can execute my rest of the functions but if I am trying to edit the data in blockchain using a function the server refreshes again and thus creating new object every time, therefore initializing the blockchain every time. How can I address this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVX9u.png)

Comment: save the Blockchain once it's created in some sort of "storage"

Comment: use database. or use localstorage to store the objects in it